# How would I loop a value within a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I apologise if this seems like I'm asking you to do my homework...I promise I'm not, I just need some help for I've never used multi Dimensional arrays before. I would ask a friend or my teacher...but its an online course therefore getting a response...takes longer then waiting for one from here. And as of now...I'm the only person taking this course, so friends don't know anything about this stuff etc etc. So...okay this program is in the making...but I'm only worried about step one so far, which is listing each student and 4 of their marks next to their name.

Ex.

```
John Smith 67 87 56 97

Jane Doe 87 56 76 92
```

etc etc etc.

So that is the goal. Simple....or so I thought. Below is some of my variables...

```
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {

    int [][] aryStudent = new int [15][4]; //This is for the 15 students that can be inputted and 4 marks each.
    int numOfStudents = 0; //number of students start of at zero until inputted...
    int marks = 0; // not in use at this given moment

public StudentGradesView(SingleFrameApplication app) {

//unimportant....

}

 private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        numOfStudents ++;
        String currentList = studentListField.getText();

        //This picks up the four different marks from four different Fields...

        aryStudent[numOfStudents][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        //now the problem is when I press the add button which adds student names and mark) it only inputs 
        //the name and the last mark inputted in the test4field. What am I missing that loops all the grades from test1Field - test4Field?

    for (int x=0; x < numOfStudents ; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {

        studentListField.setText("" + firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText() + " " + aryStudent[numOfStudents][y] + "\n" + currentList);

        }
        System.out.println("");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:
If you want to print ALL students and grades in the text field, then
you probably also need some place to remember the student names (along with the grades), right?
Declare it as:

```
String[] studentNames=new String[15];
```

Then, once your button is pressed, also add the name to the array:

```
studentNames[numOfStudents] = firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText();
```

Finally, use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build your string, then set it to the text field:

```
 numOfStudents++; // only increase the count right before the loop, after you've added the new student to the arrays. 

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int x=0; x < numOfStudents ; x++) {
    sb.append(studentNames[x]);
    for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
        sb.append(" " + aryStudent[x][y]);
    }     
    sb.append("\n");   
} 
studentListField.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate a string and display it in studentListField after you've built it up.  Right now, you're just replacing the last displayed grade with the current one, so from a user perspective, you only see the very last grade, yes?

```
for(int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++)
{
    String str = firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText();
    for(int y = 0; y < 4; x++)
    {
        str = str + " " + aryStudent[x][y];
    }
     studentListField.setText(str);
}
```

Either this solution is right, or you're going to have to explain a little better (describing exactly what you expect and what's actually happening) and I'll have to have more coffee.

Comment: I now can see four lovely digits output beside the name (when I use the string builder) however the value it outputs is always 0, regardless that I inputted say..."67" in test1Field. But what is strange is when I press the "add student" button again it outputs the correct values.

Comment: the code sets the text of that field numOfStudent times, each time overwriting the previous value... and as numOfStudents is increased before it is used to index the array, it actually ends up displaying the previous grades entered, isnt it? (try enter them more than once)

Comment: Ya actually, the zero problem as been solved thank you so much. But you're right once more, after entering a 2nd student the previous grades are still shown, but entering it again does not make a difference..